# Detectar TR clicada passar por função REACT

Tags: react

Como detectar a TH que eu cliquei e passar por parametro no React?

Queria fazer uma ordenação, mas estou com dificuldades de passar por parametro em uma função a TH que eu cliquei, alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

```
ordertableBy = async(ev) => {
    console.log(ev.target.value);
    alert('orderby' + ev.target.value);
}
<tr>
    <th onClick={ev => this.ordertableBy(ev)}>Nome</th>
    <th onClick={ev => this.ordertableBy(ev)}>Email</th>
    <th onClick={ev => this.ordertableBy(ev)}>Telefone</th>
</tr>
```

Tá retornando orderby undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De forma muito simples pode fazer assim

```
<th onClick={ev => this.ordertableBy("headerNome")}>Nome</th>
<th onClick={ev => this.ordertableBy("headerEmail")}>Email</th>
<th onClick={ev => this.ordertableBy("headerTelefone")}>Telefone</th>
```

pelo que o seu ordertableby ficaria simplesmente

```
ordertableBy = async(value) => {
    console.log(value);
    alert('orderby' + value);
}
```

**Caso queira utilizar o evento**, seria algo do genero

```
<th value="headerNome" onClick={ev => this.ordertableBy(ev)}>Nome</th>
<th value="headerEmail" onClick={ev => this.ordertableBy(ev)}>Email</th>
<th value="headerTelefone" onClick={ev => this.ordertableBy(ev)}>Telefone</th>

ordertableBy = async(ev) => {
    console.log(ev.target.value);
    alert('orderby' + ev.target.value);
}
```

PS: Normalmente usa-se  e não  quando se trata do cabeçalho da tabela

Comment: Nossa valeu José! Salvou! Obrigado!